# Do legendary actions trigger effects that happen at the beginning of the monster's turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Do legendary actions trigger effects that happen at the beginning of the monster's turn?

Consider this scenario. The monster is standing in the area of the cleric's *spirit guardians* spell. As written, the monster takes damage at the beginning of its turn as long as it's standing in the field. Suppose, however, that the monster takes a legendary action before its turn in initiative order. Does this trigger the effect of the *spirit guardians*, in addition to the normal trigger that would happen at the beginning of its regular turn?

My ruling on the matter during the game was that it did not... This would seem to violate the whole purpose of legendary actions, resulting in a massive monster nerf (i.e. taking double *spirit guardians* damage simply because it took another turn in the initiative order).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Legendary actions happen only on *other* creature's turns

The rules for [legendary actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#LegendaryActions) are clear on the fact that they do *not* count as part of the legendary creature's own turn (emphasis added):

> A legendary creature can take a certain number of special actions — called legendary actions — **outside its turn.** Only one legendary action option can be used at a time and only **at the end of another creature’s turn.**

Therefore, effects that occur during the legendary creature's turn are not triggered by legendary actions.

Comment: i wonder about a specific event, strahd von zarovich, can do legendary action and move out of its turn, and the sunlight do damage only when it start his turn in the area of effect (and not like moonbeam when he go inside it), does it mean he can run in the sun with no damage ?

Comment: @shmulikm I would say that would be good to ask as a new question, rather than a comment on an existing question.